# custom onbeforeunload alert/message

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, onbeforeunload

As many people, I tried to look for a solution to customize the onbeforeunload pop up window but I came up with no solution
So I was wondering, is it possible to hide this onbeforeunload (or make it not appear) and make a custom alert/pop up doing the same and customized?

Comment: That's completely impossible.

Comment: You can't do that, if you add an alert to the `onbeforeunload` event that will give you a confirm message. if you were to stop that from happening, the page would just close no matter what you put there instead.

Comment: So there is no way I can change/customize that at all, right?

Comment: all you can do is add a message to the alert which is displayed when asking if you want to stay on the page or leave, even then that is ignored in some browsers, @AnnArbor87

Comment: doesnt a lot of people want to do that? Why dont they allow it to be custom?
Thanks for the answer, please write it down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Onbeforeunload is a pain in th a** so I can of modify it (just the message) or know when it going to be fired (like clicking a button that goes to other page) and with javascript, disable it ( = null) and make a custom div that was hidden appear to look like a pop up.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, if you add an alert to the onbeforeunload event that will give you a confirm message. if you were to stop that from happening, the page would just close no matter what you put there instead.

all you can do is add a message to the alert which is displayed when asking if you want to stay on the page or leave, even then that is ignored in some browsers.

```
function promptMessage() {
        return "==============================\n\nINFO!!\n\n Please wait on this page until bla bla etc.\n\n==============================";
          }
window.onbeforeunload = promptMessage;
```

The reason you can't and never will be able to do this is because it allows the site owner to stop someone from leaving or bombarding the end user when they try to leave.
Really, its a good thing that this is not allowed.

Myself, I do use `onbeforeunload` when a user has entered information into a form for example but has not saved that information when they try to leave or click on a link...

Comment: How do I capture if he wants to leave? like leaving clicking on the "go back" button of the browser?

Comment: When you attach the onbeforeunload event, that will trigger anytime a user clicks a link, tries to go back or closes the window.